# How to MVC Download file in AsyncControl?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, download

I have

```
public class FileController : AsyncController
{
  public ActionResult Download(FormCollection form)
  {
    FileContentResult file = new FileContentResult(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("10k file size"),"application/vnd.xls");
    file.FileDownloadName = "test.xls";

    return file;
  }
}
```

and ofcourse, ajax form

```
<% var form = Ajax.BeginForm(...) %>
  <input type="image" src="...gif" /> // this is my 1st attempt
  <%= Ajax.ActionLink(...) %>         // 2nd attempt
<% form.EndForm(); %>
```

1. i try first method(input type=image). it reach correct Action. but no file download in client side.
2. Then i try to use Ajax.ActionLink which i really hate. i want nice image button, not link text. Again, it reach correct Action and no file download. But if i open link in another window, there's file download !!

**Q.** How to make a nice file downlaod with AsyncController

**Q.** How to make Ajax.ActionLink lok nice

Comment: at first i thought AsyncController = AjacController. but it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a way!!

just create iframe that has regular form and use jquery to trigger to.

```
$("iframe").contents().find("form").submit();
```

:D

ps credit to Firebug + Google Doc.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use Ajax to download files from the server. The reason for this is that even if you succeed to make the async request to the server in the `success` callback you will get the file contents as sent from the server and you cannot do much with this file on the client side. Remember that javascript cannot access the file system so you won't be able to save it. The way to achieve this is to have a normal HTML `<form>` which will point to the `Download` action. When this form is submitted the user will be asked to choose where he wants to save the file and the download will proceed. Also you don't need an AsyncController for this.

Here's an example:

```
public class FileController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Download()
    {
        return File(
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("10k file size"),
            "application/vnd.xls",
            "test.xls"
        );
    }
}
```

and inside your view:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("download", "file", FormMethod.Post)) { %>
    <input 
        type="image" 
        src="<%: Url.Content("~/content/images/download.png") %>" 
        value="download" 
        alt="download" 
    />
<% } %>
```

And in order to make the download button look *nice*, you could create a *nice* `download.png` image which will be used as form submit button.

Answer (score 3):

I use this:

to disable

```
$('form').removeAttr("data-ajax");
```

to enable

```
$('form').attr("data-ajax", "true");
```

for a form with 3 submit 1 to refresh 2 to download file
All post to the same ActionResult but 2 of them have param to download as csv or as pdf

when download just disable ajax submission.